# Issue while making call from ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I wanted to make the service of placing a call from from android(using ionic).
Following is the code i am using :

```
<a href="tel:+91-805-575-0232" nav-view="active" style="opacity: 1; transform: translate3d(0%, 0px, 0px);">
        Call
    </a>
```

Apart from this, have added the following line into the config.xml file:

```
<access origin="mailto:*" launch-external="yes" />
```

From desktop, i am able to get the external call functionality. But on android device, its not working.

Could someone tell me where i am making the mistake.

Comment: Have added this line in config.xml .
<access origin="tel:*" launch-external="yes" />

Sorry for the above mistake

Comment: I updated this correction to your question